# Can't Click Button in Display 2 Using Multi-Display in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two full-screen UIs (similar to control panels). I've set up two cameras and two canvases, each with a display target set to 1 and 2, respectively. I can't click on anything located in Display 2 during play mode.

I've already used the following code to activate all displays:

```
for (int i = 1; i < Display.displays.Length; i++) 
{
    Display.displays[i].Activate(); 
}
```

Using this piece of code:

```
private void CameraChange()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Escape))
    {
        isChanged = !isChanged;
        if (isChanged)
        {
            Camera1.targetDisplay = 1;
            Camera2.targetDisplay = 0;
            Canvas1.targetDisplay = 1;
            Canvas2.targetDisplay = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            Camera1.targetDisplay = 0;
            Camera2.targetDisplay = 1;
            Canvas1.targetDisplay = 0;
            Canvas2.targetDisplay = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Even after switching, there is no effect.

This works after building the project, but it doesn't work in the editor's play mode. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been like this since 2017 and has never been fixed, not even in the latest LTS. I'd love to know if there is a solution because I have the exact same problem.

See here where a user asked the same question in 2017, they knew they issue existed but left it unfixed - https://forum.unity.com/threads/buttons-not-working-properly-in-dual-screen-mode.431306/